# Does the C# MySQL library have an equivalent to the SQL SqlBulkCopy class?

Tags: c#, mysql, bulkinsert, bulk-load

I know there is MySqlBulkLoader, however it's not an equivalent as it isn't able to send data from memory and requires a file.

This is a big problem for me because I want to bulk insert a huge amount of data into a MySQL database from a program that is already doing a lot of I/O.
I can't afford to also write millions of rows into a file and then have the MySqlBulkLoader read them back again, when I already have them in memory, it makes no sense.

Why isn't there an option to do it directly from memory instead of using a file on disk?

Comment: If you use the open source MySqlConnector library instead of Oracle's Connector/NET, the equivalent MySqlBulkCopy *does* work.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I suppose I can use this alongside the rest of my code that uses the default MySQL library with no problem, right? I am using the same connection string.
Or would it cause some issues in the background? Don't they use the same driver, etc.

Comment: On the contrary, you should ditch Oracle's buggy library. The APIs are the same, but the bugs and artificial limitations aren't included.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I see, I assumed that because its the default library it's supposed to be the best one. The project is pretty large and has a lot of MySQL usage, so switching to another library entirely would be pretty big

Comment: On the contrary, Oracle has no intention of killing its cash-cow database, Oracle, and definitely no intention of making life easier for Java competitors. There's no money in free

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you use Oracle's Connector/NET. That library has several issues, mainly around async/await and Entity Framework support but one of them is the limited bulk load support. MySQL allows bulk loading from the standard console.

Instead of Oracle's driver use the [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) package. That package is used by the most popular EF provider, [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/) with 22M downloads compared to Oracle's 900K downloads. MySqlConnector by itself has 35M downloads compared to Oracle's 38M.

MySqlConnector allows bulk imports through its [MySqlBulkCopy](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlbulkcopytype/) class which works similarly to SqlBulkCopy and [accepts both DataTable and DataReader](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlbulkcopy/writetoserver/) inputs.

```
var dataTable = GetDataTableFromExternalSource();

// open the connection
using var connection = new MySqlConnection("...;AllowLoadLocalInfile=True");
await connection.OpenAsync();

// bulk copy the data
var bulkCopy = new MySqlBulkCopy(connection);
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "some_table_name";
var result = await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTable);
```

MySqlConnector's core API is the same as Connector/NET. There's a [migration guide](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/) as well that explains the differences. This guide includes the Connector/NET bugs that are fixed in MySqlConnector